# trying to get single column data with switch case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am trying to get  query the table based on role like this below but I am getting error  like this

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

I am not sure why I am getting this error

below is my query

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[getName]            
    @AccountId int,    
    @role varchar(50),
    @Activated_By nvarchar(100)            
AS            
BEGIN           

    SELECT   Name 
    FROM     pass_activationinfo 
    WHERE 
        CASE WHEN @role = 'Admin'
             THEN account_id = @AccountId
             ELSE Activated_By = @Activated_By
        END
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First variant

```
SELECT   Name 
FROM     pass_activationinfo 
WHERE 
        (@role = 'Admin' AND account_id = @AccountId)
    OR (@role <> 'Admin' AND Activated_By = @Activated_By)
```

Second variant

```
SELECT   Name 
FROM     pass_activationinfo 
WHERE 
    CASE
      WHEN @role = 'Admin' AND account_id = @AccountId THEN 1
      WHEN @role <> 'Admin' AND Activated_By = @Activated_By THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the case and use OR instead

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[getName]            
    @AccountId int,    
    @role varchar(50),
    @Activated_By nvarchar(100)            
AS            
BEGIN           

    SELECT   
        Name 
    FROM pass_activationinfo 
    WHERE 
        (
            @role = 'Admin'
            AND
            account_id = @AccountId
         )
         OR
         (
            @role <> 'Admin'
            AND
            Activated_By = @Activated_By
         )


END
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
   SELECT   Name 
    FROM     pass_activationinfo 
    WHERE 
        (( @role = 'Admin'
             and  account_id = @AccountId)
             or Activated_By = @Activated_By)
```